# breaking out of a switch within a foreach loop closure

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following code

```dart
 void onSelectionChangedFiredSources( Event event, var detail,
                                SelectCheckboxMenuComponent target)
  {
    // getItemModels returns a list of objects
      getItemModels( target.selectedItems )
        ..forEach( (item)
          {          
             switch( item.label )
             {
               case 'Ear':
                 toggleDialog( 'paper-dialog-transition-center',
                                $['ear-side-dialog']);
                 break;

               case 'Eye':
                 toggleDialog( 'paper-dialog-transition-center',
                                $['eye-side-dialog']);
                 break;

               case 'Nostril':
                 toggleDialog( 'paper-dialog-transition-center',
                                $['nostril-side-dialog']);
                 break;

               case 'Thorax':
                 toggleDialog( 'paper-dialog-transition-center',
                                $['thorax-side-dialog']);
                 break;

               default:
                 srcDataMap.add( item.label, item.selected);
             }   
          });
  }
```

When a case is triggered, I would like to break out of the foreach loop.

Note that each time the selection changes, all selections are return by the target.selectedItems expression. So if 'Ear' is the first selection, the loop is executed and when 'Eye' is then selected the list return will have both Ear and Eye.
How is this best done?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you use labels for this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Can you explain what you try to accomplish (beside ending the `forEach` which isn't possible as far as I know?

Comment: Please click on the [link](http://szgabsz91.github.io/html-components/#/input/select-checkbox-menu) and click the movies button. Goodfellas and Godfather are checked. getItemModels( target.selectedItems ) would return both labels of the checkboxes. In my case when I clicked 'Goodfellas'  a dialog would be toggled for me to make another selection with a similar component as the 'movies'. Once this second selection is made I would like to break completely from the loop without the other triggering of the checked 'Godfather' box that also triggers a dialog.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of this description. If you show a dialog and wait for user input, you must have already broken out of whatever loop you are in. Dart is single threaded, so if you are still inside the loop, the UI thread of the browser will not be able to show any dialogs. I.e., "once this second selection is made" is far too late to break out of anything.

Answer (score 8):

You can't break a `forEach` call.

You can't use `break` because it's not a loop. It's a function call, and break only works inside the current function.

You can't `return`, because that just continues with the next element.

You *can* `throw` to end the `forEach`, but that's hardly pretty.

What you can do instead is to not use `forEach` at all, and use a `for-in` loop instead, and then `break` out of that using a labeled break:

```dart
void onSelectionChangedFiredSources(Event event, var detail,
                                    SelectCheckboxMenuComponent target) {
  // getItemModels returns a list of objects
  var models = getItemModels(target.selectedItems);
  loop: for (var item in models) {
    switch (item.label) {
      case 'Ear':
      case 'Eye':
      case 'Nostril':
      case 'Thorax':
        toggleDialog('paper-dialog-transition-center',
                     $['${item.label.toLowerCase()}-side-dialog']);
        break loop;
      default:
        srcDataMap.add( item.label, item.selected);
    }   
  }
}
```

You need to use a labeled `break` because without a label it would only be breaking the `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue with your solution is the fall-through for each case. In my case, once each case is executed, the loop MUST be exited as that is the only case I need to be executed until I make another selection. The above case will not accomplish this.

Comment: Which fall-through? The only fall-through is in the default case, all the other cases break the loop. Your original code also didn't break in the dafault case.

Comment: The break comes after all case have been executed. So if Ear and Eye are selected the dialog will be triggered twice, one for each, then the loop breaks. The loop will have to break after each case for my use case.

Comment: This code breaks the loop after the first match of one of "Ear", "Eye" , etc. Can you describe exactly what it is you want it to do? It's not clear to me what "breaking the loop after *each* case" means, because breaking the loop means that there are no more cases executed.