# Flutter: Break forEach with switch and recursive call

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that this question was already asked: [breaking out of a switch within a foreach loop closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110517/breaking-out-of-a-switch-within-a-foreach-loop-closure)

however for some reason the suggested answer won't solve the issue, and the other difference is that im referencing the same function recursively.

```
Future<bool> checkSignatures(List<Widget> widgets) async {
  dynamic converted;
  bool _result = false;
  loop:
  for (var value in widgets) {
    switch (value.runtimeType) {
      case SignatureCreator:
        converted = value as SignatureCreator;
        if (await converted.data == null || await converted.data == "") {
          _result = true;
          break loop;
          break;
        }
        break;
      case PagerParserWidget:
        converted = value as PagerParserWidget;
        checkSignatures(converted.widgets);
        break;
      case ColumnParserWidget:
        converted = value as ColumnParserWidget;
        checkSignatures(converted.widgets);
        break;
    }
  }
  return _result;
}
```

i apply the suggestion of added a label to the loop and then break it, it display the result **true** but only at the end and is replaced by the others values inside the recursive call.

> I/flutter ( 5464): S: false
>
> I/flutter ( 5464): S: false
>
> I/flutter ( 5464): S: true

when only it should display true once, due to an empty/null value.

Comment: Where exactly are you printing the value of `_result`?  There is no way for the recursive calls to "replace" the value; each recursive call has its own local `_result` variable.  Note that you aren't using the values returned by the recursive calls; is that what you intended?  BTW, your question title is misleading because you aren't using `forEach` at all.

Comment: The value of result is printed in another class that calls that function, the forEach actually is used but not as the built in function, but using the java version. However i just need to break the loop when the conditional is true, but as i put on the question, i keep getting the other booleans from others SignatureCreatorWidgets that aren't empty and those override the desired value.

Comment: Could you possibly post a simpler, minimal example?  It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do and exactly what you're observing with what input data.  As it is, your recursive calls don't seem to actually do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the result variable you can return true.
And then also make sure that you use the returned value when calling the method recursively.
So you get: `if (await checkSignatures(...)) return true;`

Comment: You are right good sir! I also have forgotten to add the await to the recursive call, so that's why i received more than 1 result. I add your suggestion and is working :).